# Accessing ListBox.Item[i] IsSelected property

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

I have a listbox, and a string array added to it

```
static sting[] demo = new string[] {"cat", "dog", "bird", "horse"};

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(demo);

}
```

Then elsewhere I am trying to make a bool array based off of the listbox's selected items (it is multi select enabled)...

*the logic I am trying to do

```
//somewhere...
bool[] b = new bool[] { false, false, false, false};


//somewhere else
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    b[i] = ListBox1.Items[i].IsSelected;
}
```

This does not work. I cannot access the .Items[i] properties and have only methods available (which for this case are pointless: Equals(), GetHashCode(), GetType(), ToString()).

Using a foreach loop for the selectedIndices will not work either as it will only give me the ones that are selected (and I need to iterate through each items value true|false).

I Tried adding the System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem but that did not work either...

```
System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem[] myItems = new System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem[4];

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      myItems[i] = new System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem();
      myItems[i].Content = demo[i];
      listbox1.Items.Add(myItems[i].Content);
    }
 }
```

This part goes through fine, but later when I try to cycle through the ListBoxItems it blows up throwing a string to ListBoxItem cast error (even though I added it as a ListBoxItem object???)

Again, logic I am trying* to do but not working

```
bool tmp;
foreach(System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem li in listbox1.Items)
{
   tmp = li.IsSelected;
   // do something
}
```

I assume that trying a for loop (which realistically I would need to use anyways to point to the bool array) would fail in the same manner. I don't need to use the ListBoxItem class (actually more references to add so I would rather not use it) but I thought it would work correctly. There has to be a more efficient way to do this. In addition I would also like to know why when I add a listboxitem object to the listbox, why it has a type conversion error when I try to cycle through it later.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag your question, but it looks like you are mixing WPF classes with a WinForms project.

To mimic the IsSelected property, you can use something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  b[i] = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Contains(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried something like this?

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    if(ListBox1.Items[i].IsSelected)
        b[i] = true;
}
```

I think the compiler is doesn't have a value for IsSelected() until it's run.

Comment: You cannot access those properties anywhere; that is what has me stumped. I don't know why you can't but for some reason you cannot access the .IsSelected property